# Do System.Net.WebProxy supports all kind of proxies?

Tags: c#, proxy, socks, webproxy

There are various types of proxies.

Such as Web, Trans, Socks4 and Socks5.

Now I am using the following for using proxies but do this support all above kind of proxies ?

```
System.Net.WebProxy my_Proxy = new WebProxy(srProxyHost, irProxyPort);
```

If not what is the proper way ?

Comment: what exactly is your goal ?

Comment: @Yahia Using proxy for doing HttpWebRequests.